# IPP performance improvement on switching to VS 2013 from VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, optimization, visual-studio-2013, sse, intel-ipp

I am getting a performance improvement on switching to VS2013.

**7x7 convolution** on **14kx7k** image which was taking **2300ms** is now taking **690ms** in **VS2013**.

Though it is good, I want to understand the reason for this.

On searching the web I found out VS2010 optimizer only targets SSE2.
Any other reasons for this optimization?

Comment: Visual Studio 20012 added auto-vectorization by default. I saw a big boost in many of of applications going from 2010 to 2012. However, I saw little benefit going from 2012 to 2013.

Comment: Since IPP is pre-compiled, it does not make sense. Did you call IppInit()? Are you using same version of IPP? Can you add your code?